# Where should I store methods to make them available both to my application and to RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I need to create some methods that are available both to my application (models, views and controllers) and to RSpec.

Specifically I need to create some path_helper methods that contain critical logic. I need to make them available to RSpec so that I can run tests like:

```
controller.should redirect_to my_custom_path_helper(@object)
```

I presume that they should go somewhere in `/lib` however I'm not sure how to structure this (mixin module - if so what should I mix the module into?).

An alternative option would be if I could access Application Helpers from RSpec.

**EDIT: Please note**

*This is not a question about testing helper methods* it is about making them accessible to both the application and RSpec.

*I need to do this* because I need wrapper logic around my rails path_helpers and when I test `should redirect_to .._path` in RSpec I don't want to duplicate the logic of those path helpers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can make RSpec include a module by (in spec/spec_helper.rb):

```rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include YourModule
end
```

If you want to use routing path helpers, you can include them like this:

```rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
end
```

Answer (score 1):

the Rspec-rails gem seems to support [helper testing](http://rspec.info/rails/writing/helpers.html)

the gem can make helpers available in any of your specs : "Writing specs for your helpers is a snap. Just tell the Example Group the name of the helper and the Example Group will expose an object that includes the helper".

Comment: Hi again m_x. I'm not looking for helper testing. I'm looking to make the helpers available

Comment: the gem can make [helpers available in any of your specs](http://rspec.info/rails/writing/) : "Writing specs for your helpers is a snap. Just tell the Example Group the name of the
helper and the Example Group will expose an object that __includes the helper__". I'm a little bit sad about the -1 after all the time i spent trying to help you.

Comment: You're completely right - I did it because although your subsequent comment explained your reasoning the first one was pertaining to testing the helpers. Either way I apologise, your help has been invaluable and it was rude of me to downvote it. If you can edit it to include your subsequent comment I can change the downvote. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried it, but this looks like an interesting approach to the problem:
[Adding rspec test for library module doesn't seem to pickup Expectations and Matchers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987080/adding-rspec-test-for-library-module-doesnt-seem-to-pickup-expectations-and-mat)

> A model we often use when testing Modules is to include the module in either a class created for the test (inside the spec file) or included inside the spec itself.