# How can you include a mixin to make it available to all of your observers, models, controllers and RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mixins

I want to create a set of methods that are available to my models, controllers, views and RSpec.

**Please note** I don't want to *test* these methods in RSpec, I want them *available* to RSpec to use.

The reason I want to do this is that I have some helpers which override the Rails `path_helper` methods. Since those path helper methods get used directly in all of these different places I need to mix them in as such.

Comment: You shouldn't be using the path helpers in your models. If you are, your models might be doing things they shouldn't be doing.

Comment: How is this different than your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435525/where-should-i-store-methods-to-make-them-available-both-to-my-application-and-t)?

Comment: Will - it's not it's just that I didn't get an answer to that. @Beerlington - fair point and on thinking about it further I don't actually need them in the model

Answer (score 0):

Hm, it is several ways to achieve your goal, one of them is to include your module with methods direct in `ActiveRecord::Base`, 'ApplicationController' and `Rspec`.
Not sure about RSpec (I don't quite sign with it's class/module structure) but you can do something like this in some initializer file:

```
class ActiveRecord::Base
 include MyModuleWithAwesomeMethods
end

class ApplicationController
 include MyModuleWithAwesomeMethods
end
```

etc. for other classes/modules
Hope it will help you.