# undefined local variable or method `root_path' Hartl's Tutorial Chapter 5.3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

So my first question on Stackoverflow..... =]

My tests in Chapter 5.3.2 of [Michael Hartl's RoR Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/filling-in-the-layout#sec-rails_routes) are all failing, when the tutorial says it should be passing (tutorial says 'about', 'contact', and 'help' should pass... but all of mine fail). Everything til now worked fine, but I changed the

```
get 'static_pages/help'
```

to

```
match '/help', to: 'static_pages#help'
```

so that my

### **config/routes.rb**

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do

  root to: 'static_pages#home'

  match '/help', to: 'static_pages#help'
  match '/about', to: 'static_pages#about'
  match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
```

and then everything went to hell. All my tests fails with a undefined local variable or method 'root_path' or 'about_path' etc. (see below, Terminal Output). But here are my relevant files... Just in case anyone is curious, all the files are exactly what Hartl has. I basically copied and pasted each file's content.

Can someone help me?????? Thanks!

### **spec/static_pages_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Static pages" do

  describe "Home page" do

    it "should have the h1 'Sample App'" do
      visit root_path
      page.should have_selector('h1', text: 'Sample App')
    end

    it "should have the base title" do
      visit root_path
      page.should have_selector('title',
                        text: "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App")
    end

    it "should not have a custom page title" do
      visit root_path
      page.should_not have_selector('title', text: '| Home')
    end
  end

  describe "Help page" do

    it "should have the h1 'Help'" do
      visit help_path
      page.should have_selector('h1', text: 'Help')
    end

    it "should have the title 'Help'" do
      visit help_path
      page.should have_selector('title',
                        text: "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Help")
    end
  end

  describe "About page" do

    it "should have the h1 'About'" do
      visit about_path
      page.should have_selector('h1', text: 'About Us')
    end

    it "should have the title 'About Us'" do
      visit about_path
      page.should have_selector('title',
                    text: "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | About Us")
    end
  end

  describe "Contact page" do

    it "should have the h1 'Contact'" do
      visit contact_path
      page.should have_selector('h1', text: 'Contact')
    end

    it "should have the title 'Contact'" do
      visit contact_path
      page.should have_selector('title',
                    text: "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Contact")
    end
  end
end
```

### **Terminal output with input 'rspec spec/'**

```
FFFFFFFFF

Failures:

  1) Static pages Contact page should have the h1 'Contact'
     Failure/Error: visit contact_path
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `contact_path' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_4:0x007fd2093855f8>
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:55:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) Static pages Contact page should have the title 'Contact'
     Failure/Error: visit contact_path
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `contact_path' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_4:0x007fd208cbeb20>
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:60:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) Static pages Help page should have the h1 'Help'
     Failure/Error: visit help_path
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `help_path' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_2:0x007fd2094c02b0>
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:27:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  4) Static pages Help page should have the title 'Help'
     Failure/Error: visit help_path
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `help_path' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_2:0x007fd209649208>
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:32:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  5) Static pages About page should have the h1 'About'
     Failure/Error: visit about_path
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `about_path' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_3:0x007fd208f16d00>
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:41:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  6) Static pages About page should have the title 'About Us'
     Failure/Error: visit about_path
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `about_path' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_3:0x007fd2094f7990>
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:46:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  7) Static pages Home page should not have a custom page title
     Failure/Error: visit root_path
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `root_path' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1:0x007fd208d30b08>
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:19:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  8) Static pages Home page should have the base title
     Failure/Error: visit root_path
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `root_path' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1:0x007fd208e0cb80>
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:13:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  9) Static pages Home page should have the h1 'Sample App'
     Failure/Error: visit root_path
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `root_path' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1:0x007fd209607268>
     # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.30216 seconds
9 examples, 9 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:54 # Static pages Contact page should have the h1 'Contact'
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:59 # Static pages Contact page should have the title 'Contact'
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:26 # Static pages Help page should have the h1 'Help'
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:31 # Static pages Help page should have the title 'Help'
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:40 # Static pages About page should have the h1 'About'
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:45 # Static pages About page should have the title 'About Us'
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:18 # Static pages Home page should not have a custom page title
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:12 # Static pages Home page should have the base title
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:7 # Static pages Home page should have the h1 'Sample App'
```

Comment: Have you included the `url_helpers`? See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8953304/84631).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mischa's answer will hopefully fix most of those problems, but your tests may still fail on the root_path issue.

Have you removed index.html like so: `git rm public/index.html`

And don't forget to commit your changes with: `git commit -am "Message"`

Comment: Can you put your code on github? There is probably something obvious that will become more apparent if I can look at it closer

Comment: And the commit would just add files to the repo, you probably don't actually need to do it though to get the tests running

Comment: I'm just curious... why is it throwing me an undefined local variable or method error? is it because it doesn't recognize what *_path means?

Comment: @sambaek, the problem may be that you didn't include the `url_helpers`. Without that RSpec doesn't recognize the `*_path` methods and throws that error. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8953304/84631) on SO.

Comment: github code: https://github.com/sambaek/sample_app

i just went ahead and worked through the rest of the chapter of the tutorial, but the code still throws the exact same errors... thanks guys!

Comment: @sambaek, I looked at your Github repo and the `url_helpers` don't seem to be included in `spec_helper.rb`. I believe including them will fix your problem.

Comment: I think you should remove one of those Rspec.configure blocks, Just keep the one that's inside the spork prerun block - ps I'm just running your tests now, will report on what I find

Comment: Oh, yes, I see. Sorry. Are you using Spork? Did you try restarting the Spork server?

Comment: omg... it was a spork issue. THANK YOU SO MUCH! i really really appreciate the help guys..

Comment: solved... thanks! without you guys, i would have been stuck until i restarted my computer or something haha. thanks again

Answer (score 12):

I'll put this as an answer because the solution (from @mischa) is buried in the [comments under @marflar's answer: try restarting Spork to solve this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12240868/undefined-local-variable-or-method-root-path-hartls-tutorial-chapter-5-3-2/16375807#comment16406832_12240937).

Comment: This is on the borderline of an acceptable answer. At the very least, put a link back to the comment that gave the correct answer.

Comment: It is the tenth comment on the accepted answer on this page.  Can I link to a comment?  My initial confusion was due to the fact that the comment that had the answer that worked for me was hidden when I entered the page.

Comment: [Yes, you can link to comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12240868/undefined-local-variable-or-method-root-path-hartls-tutorial-chapter-5-3-2/12240937#comment16406832_12240937), though in all fairness it may not be entirely obvious to a new user where to find the URI. The post time at the end of the comment (such as `May 4 at 15:45` for [mine above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12240868/undefined-local-variable-or-method-root-path-hartls-tutorial-chapter-5-3-2/12240937#comment23468060_16375807)) is the link.

Comment: Thanks Jerry -- probably should have searched on doing that as well.

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem in this chapter, just change in config/routes.rb *root to: 'static_pages#home'* **to** *root :to =>  'static_pages#home'* and it's start work. you can also check all routes with *rake routes*.

Comment: actually because i was using ruby 1.9.3, the hash syntax shouldn't have affected it. `to: somethingcheck` is the same as `:to => something`. check which version of ruby you were using... if 1.8.7, then you would need to use your method

Answer (score 1):

In your Gemfile, change the rspec-rails line to: 
    gem 'rspec-rails', '2.12.0'

This version of rspec supports the approach Hartl is using at that point in the book.

Answer (score 1):

```
  root :to => 'static_pages#home' 
  match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help',    via: 'get'
  match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about',   via: 'get'
  match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact', via: 'get'
```

works for me

test results: 9 examples 0 failures

urls seem to have changed like this now:

```
http://localhost:3000/about
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using the same tutorial and ran into the exact same problem! You might've thought it was spork that fixed this but that wasn't it. The reason it worked is because you went ahead and upgraded the Rspec in the next section. It only works with the upgraded rspec - the old rspec was why your tests didn't pass. The site is wrong in that it tells users that the tests will pass before also changing the Rspec

Comment: What version of rspec did you use?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. My fix was to include the following line in spec_helper.rb

```
config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
```

BTW gems are:

```
gem 'rails', '4.1.5'
gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0'
```

and I also removed all the Guard and Spork stuff.